# How to Pass CDK column and row definitions through a component

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I'm trying to pass column and row definitions through a component, and I'm not sure how to do it, or if its even possible. I want to do this, so (a) the client component can specify the data, columns and rows definitions, the wrapping component can render a cdk-table plus other paging ornamentation.

```
<app-wrapper-table [data]="data">

  <ng-container cdkColumnDef="firstName">
    <th cdk-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>First Name</th>
    <td cdk-cell *cdkCellDef="let item">{{item.firstName}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container cdkColumnDef="lastName">
    <th appHeaderCell *cdkHeaderCellDef>Last Name</th>
    <td cdk-cell *cdkCellDef="let item">{{item.lastName}}></td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container cdkColumnDef="availability">
    <th appHeaderCell *cdkHeaderCellDef>Availability</th>
    <td cdk-cell *cdkCellDef="let item">{{item.availability}}></td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr cdk-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr cdk-row *cdkRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>

</app-wrapper-table>
```

The wrapper table looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, TemplateRef, ContentChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-wrapper-table',
  templateUrl: './my-wrapper-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-wrapper-table.component.scss']
})
export class MyWrapperTableComponent implements {
  @Input() data: any[];
  @ContentChild(TemplateRef) template: TemplateRef<any>;
}

<div>
  <div>Some Heading</div>
</div>
<table cdk-table [dataSource]="data">
  <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"></ng-container>
</table>
<div class="paging-controls">
  <div class="paging-buttons">
    <button type="button">Previous</button>
    <button type="button">Next</button>
  </div>
  <div class="paging-size">
    <span>Page Size</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The error I get is

> Error: Missing definitions for header, footer, and row; cannot
>   determine which columns should be rendered.

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sdogaf?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cdk table needs its definitions at init time, there are none if you try to provide them later on via templates or ng-content.

Why not pull the table definition inside the content of your wrapper element and use it with an ng-content in the wrapper component like in this [modified stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3wuem5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)?

Comment: It's because I want the user of the wrapper component to define the columns, otherwise the wrapper component is not generic enough, and in my app, I have a dozen tables, and I'd have to create a dozen wrapper components.

Comment: I don't see why in your stackblitz (but it may be because it is a trimmed down version of the problem). In the modified stackblitz I just pulled up a generic element, you would still use the same wrapper everywhere, it would just not include the cdk-table directive.

Comment: I think this is probably close to what I'm looking for; I'm going to investigate this weekend. I spotted a method on cdkTable called "addColumnDef" led me to this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/material2-beta11-vmwjpe?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: David I like your solution. Thank you. I'm marking it as the answer.

Comment: Is there a workaround to get `ng-content` working inside the table?